# stuck with positioning images using css

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Im making a website, and I need to include a page about the actress Meryl Streep. Im trying to postion an image of her beside her awards. The picture below shows what my page looks like right now. I was wondering how do I Make it so that the picture aligns to the right of the text instead of below it? Thanks.

[image]

This is the html code:

```
 <div class="info">
<a id="awards"><h2>Awards: </h2></a>
<h3>Academy Awards</h3>
<h4>Won</h4>
<ol>
<li>Best Supporting Actress (Kramer vs. Kramer) - 1979</li>
<li>Best Actress (Sophie's Choice) - 1982</li>
<li>Best Actress (The Iron Lady) - 2011</li>
</ol>
<h4>Nominated</h4>
<ol>
<li>Best Supporting Actress (The Deer Hunter) - 1978</li>
<li>Best Actress (The French Lieutenant's Woman) - 1981</li>
<li>Best Actress (Silkwood) - 1983</li>
<li>Best Actress (Out of Africa) - 1985</li>
<li>Best Actress (Ironweed) - 1987</li>
<li>Best Actress (A Cry in the Dark) - 1988</li>
<li>Best Actress (Postcards from the Edge) - 1990</li>
<li>Best Actress (The Bridges of Madison County) 1995</li>
<li>Best Actress (One True Thing) - 1998</li>
<li>Best Actress (Music of the Heart) - 1999</li>
 <li>Best Supporting Actress (Adaption) - 2002</li>
 <li>Best Actress (The Devil Wears Prada) - 2006</li>
 <li>Best Actress (Doubt) - 2008</li>
 <li>Best Actress (Julie & Julia) - 2009</li>
 <li>Best Actress (August: Osage County) - 2013</li>
 <li>Best Supporting Actress (Into the Woods) - 2014</li>
</ol>
 <div class="oscar">
 <img src="oscar.jpg" alt="Picture of Meryl with an oscar" width="300" 
 height="400"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS for div:info:
    .info {
        background-color: white;
        border: groove;
        border-top-right-radius: 3em;

Comment: Please post the code you have

Comment: Ok I have eddited the question, although the html code i pastes just displays the info.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using table ?

```
<table>
<tr><td>1.Best Actor</td>
<td><img src="image.jpg"></td>
</tr>
```

and so on....

It might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use float properties to float it
http://rao5s.vn/29-0-ipad-air-3g-va-ipad-3-3g-mau-trang-gia-tot.html

```
<div style="float: left;">
  1. Best Actress
  2. Best Actress
  3. Best Actress
  4. Best Actress
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
  <img src="link-to-image-file" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the second "ol" the styles:

width: auto;
float: left;

then it works.